# Express res.render renders the wrong file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I've setup a server to use Handlebars as a view engine. Using `res.render` on a GET request at the main page renders the page properly, however using `res.render` to render a page other than the main page renders the same page. Even using `res.send` will send the main handlebars page but leaving the expressions unchanged.

Here's my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const subdomain = require("express-subdomain");
const handlebars = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
const subdomain = express.Router();

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views/layouts"));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.engine("handlebars", handlebars({
    "layoutsDir": path.join(__dirname + "/views/layouts")
}));

subdomain.use(bodyParser.json());
subdomain.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended": true}));

subdomain.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("books/index.html");
});

subdomain.get("/books", (req, res) => {
    let data = {};

    res.render("books", data);
});

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(subdomain("subdomain", subdomain));

app.get("/index", async (req, res) => {
    let data = {};

    res.render("main", data);
});

server = app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("listening to requests on port " + 8080);
});
```

Obviously I would like to generate a page other than just the main page on my site. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing twice the same thing

Instead of:

```
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views/layouts"));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.engine("handlebars", handlebars({
    "layoutsDir": path.join(__dirname + "/views/layouts")
}));
```

Maybe

```
// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views/layouts"));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
```

Edited:

Check the edit, "hbs" instead of "handlebars". I have this on my package.json dependencies "hbs": "~4.0.4", or check github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter por a complete boilerplate

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately... Removing the first or third line gives me an error. Editing the third line to say `app.engine("handlebars", handlebars());` doesn't return an error, but express still renders the wrong page.

Comment: Checj the edit, "hbs" instead of "handlebars". I have this on my package.json dependencies `"hbs": "~4.0.4",`

or check https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter por a complete boilerplate

Comment: Switching the rendering engine to "hbs" worked, thanks :) If anyone else stumbles upon this and makes the switch, I obviously had to install the hbs package, require it, and then follow the different formatting for helper functions which I found on the npm page for hbs.

Comment: Great! I edited the answer, please mark it as the solution for helping other users.